# How to get value of time from a column, extend the duration, and then create event on google calendar?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

**OBJECTIVE**
Create event on calendar depending on submitted *date* *time* and *duration*

**Problem**

- Retrieving value of time from a column,
- Extend the duration of the booked time depending on submitted *duration*
- Create event based on the duration

**My Code**

```
  var dateCol = 3; ////this column retrieve DATE from google form
  var timeCol = 4; //this column retrieve TIME from google form
  var durCol = 5; ////this column retrieve STRING from google form
  var serviceCol = 6;
  var eventIDCol = 21;
  var appCol = 23
  var revCol = 24;
  var response = e.range;
  var rRow = response.getRow()
 
    var resprange = responsesheet.getRange(rLR,1,1,rLC);
    var respdata = resprange.getValues();
    copysheet.appendRow(respdata[0]);
    var eventTitle = copysheet.getRange(rRow,serviceCol).getValue();
    var startDate = copysheet.getRange(rRow,dateCol).getValue();
    var startTime = copysheet.getRange(rRow,timeCol).getValue();

    startDate.getTime().setHours(startTime.getHours());
    startDate.getTime().setHours(startTime.getMinutes());
    var endTime = new Date(startDate);
    var duration = copysheet.getRange(rRow,durCol).getValue();
    if (duration == 'Less than 45 minutes') {
      endTime.setMinutes(startDate.getTime().getMinutes()+45);
    } else if (duration == 'Less than 1 hour') {
      endTime.setMinutes(startDate.getTime().getMinutes()+60);
    } else if (duration == 'Less than 2 hours') {
      endTime.setMinutes(startDate.getTime().getMinutes()+120);
    } else {
      endTime.setMinutes(startDate.getTime().getMinutes()+180);
    };
    var conflicts = calendar.getEvents(new Date(startDate), new Date(endTime));
    if (conflicts.length < 1) {
    var event = calendar.createEvent(eventTitle, new Date(startDate), new Date(endTime));
    var eventID = event.getId().split('@')[0];
    copysheet.getRange(rRow,appCol).setValue("approve");
    copysheet.getRange(rRow,eventIDCol).setValue(eventID);
    } else {
    copysheet.getRange(rRow,appCol).setValue("conflict");
    }
```

NOTE: I am sure that the problem is with retrieving the time value and adding minutes part. Should I convert time value to string first? Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: date.getTime() returns a number.  So you can't then chain something that expects a date - like .setHours()

Comment: thank you for the reply, what is the best way to chain them together? just get rid of getTime()?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it was a super silly mistake, thank you @James for the hint. I simply got rid of getTime() and it works perfect. This is the code:

```
startDate.setHours(startTime.getHours());
    startDate.setHours(startTime.getMinutes());
    var endTime = new Date(startDate);
    var duration = copysheet.getRange(rRow,durCol).getValue();
    if (duration == 'Less than 45 minutes') {
      endTime.setMinutes(startDate.getMinutes()+45);
    } else if (duration == 'Less than 1 hour') {
      endTime.setMinutes(startDate.getMinutes()+60);
    } else if (duration == 'Less than 2 hours') {
      endTime.setMinutes(startDate.getMinutes()+120);
    } else {
      endTime.setMinutes(startDate.getMinutes()+180);
    };
```

Notice that after value of time has been retrieved, no need to use getTime() anymore.